# Change the value of a textarea in way that its react prop "value" changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, instagram

I need to change value of textarea(commnet box of instagram.com) through a chrome extension's script(content script) so that its react prop "value"(this.props.value) changes and on triggering submit event on the parent form element the comment get posted.

If I trigger the event after changing the textarea's value with `$commentBox.value = "comment"` and then trigger submit event on the form element the comment doesnt get posted and I checked through react devtools that prop value is "". I think prop value changes only on keydown/keypress but faking keydown/keypress after changing the value also doesnt work

how can I insert the comment through javascript and then post it?
also see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567683/submit-a-comment-on-instagram-posts-using-jquery-or-pure-javascript/53874740#53874740)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*was just checking questions I'd asked and found this one*

This cannot be done through an extension's script because using javascript there we can only fire untrusted events which woukld get filtered. **This would be possible only with puppeteer**